# vb.net Data Gridview REfresh

Tags: vb.net

i am having some issues updating a table that i have in a VB.net Windows Forms in VS 2012

i have setup the database from a service Data base, it just need a small amount of data stored locally

what i am trying to do when i create a new user it update the data grid view

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BDate1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    BDate1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

    If fname.Text <> "" And lname.Text <> "" Then
        If Not cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Open()
        End If
        ' cn1.Open()
        If rb1.Checked Then
            gen = rb1.Text.ToString
        ElseIf rb2.Checked Then
            gen = rb2.Text.ToString
        End If

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StudentTB (FirstName,LastName,Birthday,Avatar,Gender,Grade) values('" & fname.Text & "', '" & lname.Text & "', '" & BDate1.Text & "', '" & AvtarNM.Text & "', '" & gen & "', '" & TxtGrade.Text & "')"
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        ' cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        fname.Text = ""
        lname.Text = ""
```

the issue is that i can clear the table and reload it with button but it does not show the updated values with out closing the application then reopening it, i have tried a few thing and nothing seems to refresh the connection and or update the database. any help would help.

thanks

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    'DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
     Database1DataSet1.StudentTB.Clear()
    ' Database1DataSet1.refresh()
    ' Dim myda As String
    '  cmd.Dispose()
    ' cmd.Connection = cn
    'Me.Database1DataSet1.Clear()
     Me.StudentTBTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet1.StudentTB)
    '  'myda = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)


End Sub
```

here is the full code

```
    Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Student

    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Nate\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsApplication9\WindowsApplication9\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Private dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim gen As String
    Dim bs As New BindingSource
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    Private Sub Student_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database1DataSet1.avTable' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.AvTableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet1.avTable)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database1DataSet1.StudentTB' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.StudentTBTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet1.StudentTB)
        cmd.Connection = cn
        Form1.Hide()



    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If AvTableBindingSource.Position + 1 < AvTableBindingSource.Count Then
            AvTableBindingSource.MoveNext()
            Button7.PerformClick()
            ' Otherwise, move back to the first item.
        Else
            AvTableBindingSource.MoveFirst()
            Button7.PerformClick()
        End If

        ' Force the form to repaint.
        Me.Invalidate()



    End Sub


    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(ID.Text)
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        BDate1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        BDate1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

        If fname.Text <> "" And lname.Text <> "" Then
            If Not cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cn.Open()
            End If
            ' cn1.Open()
            If rb1.Checked Then
                gen = rb1.Text.ToString
            ElseIf rb2.Checked Then
                gen = rb2.Text.ToString
            End If

            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StudentTB (FirstName,LastName,Birthday,Avatar,Gender,Grade) values('" & fname.Text & "', '" & lname.Text & "', '" & BDate1.Text & "', '" & AvtarNM.Text & "', '" & gen & "', '" & TxtGrade.Text & "')"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
            bs.DataSource = dt
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
            cn.Close()
            fname.Text = ""
            lname.Text = ""




        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub genPCI()
        If rb1.Checked Then
            gen = rb1.Text.ToString
        ElseIf rb2.Checked Then
            gen = rb2.Text.ToString
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function ChangeFormat(ByVal dtm As DateTime, ByVal format As String) As String
        Return dtm.ToString(format)
    End Function



    Private Sub Closestudent_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Closestudent.Click
        Form1.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        bs.EndEdit()
        dataAdapter.Update(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        ' dt.Load(Command.ExecuteReader())
        'Database1DataSet1.Reset()
        'DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()
        ' DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        ' Me.StudentTBTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet1.StudentTB)
        ' StudentTBBindingSource.ResetBindings(True)
        ' Database1DataSet1.refresh()
        ' Dim myda As String
        '  cmd.Dispose()
        ' cmd.Connection = cn
        ' StudentTBBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
        'Database1DataSet1.StudentTB.Clear()

        '  'myda = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        ' DataGridView1.DataSource = Database1DataSet1.StudentTB
    End Sub


End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    bs.EndEdit()
    dataadapter.Update(dt)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

End Sub
```

UPDATE

or you can use bindingdatasource and delare it on your form class

```
Dim bs As New BindingSource
```

and in datagridview .. in button1_click

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
bs.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
```

So, if updated then will show after button4_click

Comment: no luck I tried that and it does exactly what all the other things do it seems to reload the table but it does not show the new data that i have added. the only way I can seem to get the added data to show is by reloading the program

Comment: i tried that i think i am missing something here is the start of the code Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Nate\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsApplication9\WindowsApplication9\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Private dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim gen As String
    Dim bs As New BindingSource

Comment: i am lost to where you want me to add the code "in datagridview" Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
bs.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.DataSource = bs

Comment: button 1   
             cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StudentTB (FirstName,LastName,Birthday,Avatar,Gender,Grade) values('" & fname.Text & "', '" & lname.Text & "', '" & BDate1.Text & "', '" & AvtarNM.Text & "', '" & gen & "', '" & TxtGrade.Text & "')"
            '  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
            bs.DataSource = dt
            DataGridView1.DataSource = bs
            cn.Close()
            fname.Text = ""
            lname.Text = ""

Comment: all it seems to do now is wipe the table clear and display no data in it. with both button 1 and 4

Comment: i have posted the full code that may help as i am still a bit lost to what i have got wrong.... i would not think it would be this hard

Comment: in button1 .. there's should no **cn.close()** .. do that if you no need anymore with the connection

Comment: it looks like it reload with the updated button but still no luck the data is not updating

Answer (score 0):

```
    Datagridview1.datasource = nothing
Dataset.reset
dim cmd as new sqldataadapter
cmd = "SELECT * FROM YOUR_DATABSE", con
con.open
cmd.fill(Dataset)
datagridview1.datasource = dataset(0).defaultview
```

Add these code to you button insert

Comment: DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        Database1DataSet1.Reset()
        dataAdapter = "SELECT * FROM StudentTB", con
        cn.Open()
        dataAdapter.Fill(Database1DataSet1)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Database1DataSet1(0).defaultview

Comment: i just tried that but i am getting errors  the select command comes up with value string can not be converted to a sqldataadapter

Comment: i have tried this code `Dim strSQL As String

        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        Database1DataSet1.Reset()

        'Dim cmd2 As New SqlDataAdapter
        strSQL = "SELECT * FROM StudentTB"
        cn.Open()
        DataGridView1.DataSource.SelectCommand = strSQL
        'con.open()'

        dataAdapter.Fill(Database1DataSet1.StudentTB)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Database1DataSet1.StudentTB` with no luck either

Comment: What error you get? and you miss something,, before cn.open,, you must put ',cn' after studenttb"

Comment: `strSQL = "SELECT * FROM StudentTB",cn` you mean like this i get the meessage end statement expected okay i add the cn in inside the quote marks and that seems to work but now it get System.NullReferenceException

Comment: Does your database have any data? can you provide your error image?

Answer (score 0):

okay after a lot of playing around this seem to fix my issue http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx well all i can say it is working no idea why but it works.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.StudentTBBindingSource
    GetData("select * from StudentTB")

End Sub

Private Sub GetData(ByVal selectCommand As String)

    Try
        ' Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a  
        ' valid connection string for a Northwind SQL Server sample 
        ' database accessible to your system. 
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Nate\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WindowsApplication9\WindowsApplication9\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"


        ' Create a new data adapter based on the specified query. 
        Me.dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connectionString)

        ' Create a command builder to generate SQL update, insert, and 
        ' delete commands based on selectCommand. These are used to 
        ' update the database. 
        Dim commandBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)

        ' Populate a new data table and bind it to the BindingSource. 
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)
        Me.StudentTBBindingSource.DataSource = table

        ' Resize the DataGridView columns to fit the newly loaded content. 
        ' Me.DataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns( _
        '  DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader)
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show("To run this example, replace the value of the " + _
            "connectionString variable with a connection string that is " + _
            "valid for your system.")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using ComboBox To Search

```
sql = " select * from english_language where lang=' " & ComboBox2.Text & " ' "   

da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

Dim dt As New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.Refresh()
```

Comment: This is not an advised approach - you are leaving the code wide open to SQL injection attacks (assuming the Combobox allows free-form input). Take a look at [OleDbCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to btnClear.

```
DataGridView.DataSource = 0
```

Press clear button. After that click the reload button that you coded.

I think it will reset and reload the data in data grid view.